# Reading a PDF using pdf-reader gem

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, pdf-reader

I have just started working on Selenium automation using Ruby.
I have a requirement to read a PDF contents and compare it with my application.
For that i am making use of the pdf-reader gem.

```
reader.pages.each do |page|
    str=page.text
    puts"#{str}"
end
```

'str' displays the entire text in the PDF. However, i see that some of the words are overlapped by other words.Overlapped words are not displayed in the console at all. Is there any way to display the entire text?

Thanks